# making picture frame widget take up entire screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, picture-frame-widget

On my Galaxy S II, I've added the Picture Frame widget to the second page. It's the only object on that page, but it only takes up 1/4th of the available space.

I tried adding 3 more frames on a lark, but that was more annoying than anything. Ideally, my one picture frame would take up the entire page. But I don't know how to resize it? Surely this is possible...?

Comment: If you want a picture to take up the whole screen, why not just use it as a wallpaper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Galaxy S2 (Gingerbread 2.3.3) you can resize the picture frame widget this way:

1. First drag the picture frame to the left top
2. The picure selection pops up, select pictures that you want and klick OK (save)
3. Press the picture frame until the phone vibrates and release fast. The display will now show a grid on the screen.
4. Hold the right bottom "slider" and resize the frame as you like it
5. Finished!! :D

I have standard launcher as delivered so this should do the trick for most of you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't re size widget in Android Gingerbread. I don't have SII and can't say but many widget comes in different sizes like 1x1, 1x4 etc. Try scrolling to see if there is other sized picture frame.

Comment: This is true, Honeycomb (version 3.2 and above in particular) are the first versions where the stock Android launcher has options to resize widgets. These will presumably be coming to phones in with Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4).

Answer (score 1):

As Roxan says the built-in picture widget in Android 2.3 isn't resizable. As an alternative, you should be able to find  many alternative picture and photo widgets from a quick search in the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store), from a quick look many of those offer a range of sizes.

Alternatively you could use an alternate Android launcher that allows you to resize widgets, but this will also change a lot of other things about how your home screen works. If you want to go down that route, I believe that Launcher Pro and ADW Launcher (amongst others) allow you to resize widgets.